# sending arguments from one function to another through event handler

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two functions here, the first one is triggered by a button and it is meant to trigger a second function which will change the inner html of that first buttons accompanying html area.

My problem is how to pass the arguments from the first function INTO the second one to the button and textfield have the same idnumber.

```
    function doLoad(idnumber, id) {
        var file = _(id).files[0];
        _("Btn1_QP_"+idnumber).style.display = "none";
        _("Display_QP_"+idnumber).innerHTML = "Image uploading......";
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("stPic", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "pho_stem3.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);    
     }

    function completeHandler(event) {
        _("Display_QP").innerHTML = 'wahooo';
    } 
}
```

In function doLoad idnumber is given by the button and used to identify the proper button with`("Btn1_QP_"+idnumber)`

how can i achieve this same selective ability in the second function `completeHandler` in the event listener.

I have tried

```
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler(idnumber), false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", ("completeHandler"+idnumber), false);
```

both dont work. how can i preserve and transmit the original argument from doLoad...

Comment: is your completeHandler function is depending on response of ajax call ?

Comment: yes, it is. CompleteHandler fires when ajax gives the correct response

Comment: After re-indenting your code it looks like it's a bit malformed. Do you have missing `function(){` at the top or is that dangling `}` just a typo?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution for this, I have found no question like this on any website and I am excited to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the same id number in response of ajax like this:

```
function doLoad(idnumber, id) {
    var file = _(id).files[0];
    _("Btn1_QP_" + idnumber).style.display = "none";
    _("Display_QP_" + idnumber).innerHTML = "Image uploading......";
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("stPic", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    ajax.open("POST", "pho_stem3.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
         completeHandler(idnumber);
    }
}
}

function completeHandler(idnumber) {
   _("Display_QP_" + idnumber).innerHTM = 'wahooo';
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention why the OP should prefer `onreadystatechange` over the mozilla specific `onload` event

Comment: is there a 'for each' I should use, there are numerous idnumber values being defined in php. idnumber = 1, idnumber = 2, idnumber = 3. etc. this way only targets the first one generated on the page and none of the others

Comment: so  are you are targeting  multiple buttons ?

Comment: yes, all buttons and html fields with the same name but different idnumber generated from php ("Btn1_QP_" + idnumber)

Comment: How can I loo through them all with the existing code that ZAN has supplied idnumber must be preserved until completeHandler function has ended, for each unique idnumber

Comment: store all id in `pho_stem3.php` in array and use json to encode pass it on  and then decode it in response , then loop through  it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76857/discussion-between-peter-and-zan).